# I am trying to make a collapsable menu with only 1 open at a time pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

Here is my code and the JSfiddle code, I am having an issue now that if one is opened and you try to close it again it won't close.

https://jsfiddle.net/k68z3aLv/

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
 
   var b;
   for(b = 0; b < coll.length; b++) {
     
   if(coll[b] != coll[i]) {
    if(coll[b].getAttribute('id') == 'submenuopened')
    {
      coll[b].classList.remove("active");
     coll[b].setAttribute("id",'');
      var content3 = coll[b].nextElementSibling;
       content3.style.display = "none";
             
   // sleep(0);
   }
   }
   }
    
    this.classList.toggle("active");
 if(this.getAttribute('id') == 'submenuopened') {
  this.setAttribute("id",'ha');
 } else { this.setAttribute("id", "submenuopened"); }
 
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display == 'block'){
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a [working example & tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp).

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a much simpler way to iterate through your DOM elements and also to make your code more understandable.

<kbd>[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c6df2rsh/)</kbd>

These are the edits required. HTML and CSS are very small adjustments, the JS part is the interesting one.

### HTML

```
<div class="collapsible">
  <header>
    Open Section 1
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>

...
```

#### Reasoning

Unless your buttons to open and close the collapsibles are far away from the actual content (which is not the case you mentioned here), semantically it's good for the whole element to be grouped together.

### CSS

```
.collapsible header {
  ...
}

.collapsible.is-active .content {
  display: block;
}
```

#### Reasoning

The only change required here is adjusting the CSS to target the `header` element, as the `.collapsible` class is now applied to the parent.

Also, we add a simple semantic class that will tell us which one is currently active, and show it.

### JS

```
const collapsibles = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"));

function toggleVisibility(e) {
  const parent = e.target.parentElement;

  parent.classList.toggle("is-active");

  collapsibles.forEach(collapsible => {
    if(collapsible === parent) return;

    collapsible.classList.remove("is-active")
  });
}

collapsibles.forEach(collapsible => {
    collapsible.querySelector("header").addEventListener("click", toggleVisibility);
});
```

#### Reasoning

1. First you get an array of parent DOM elements and store those into a variable. You will use that to decide which one to show and which one to hide.
2. On each of those DOM elements, you attach your event listener using simpler and more readable Array methods instead of `for` loops.
3. You refactor your handler into a simple function you can reuse. All that this function does, is make sure you `toggle` the current active one if you click on itself, and close all the rest.

Comment: like that you used a named function when binding events, when using anonymous functions events won't unbind properly.

Comment: @lkroneman yea, been there many times ;) Also just makes everything more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I little bit optimized your code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user1701/snowbr85/), `id` was removed because `active` class is enough, open/close moved to CSS because it's a better way to do it, extra code was removed to look it more clear

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

for (let i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   for(let n = 0; n < coll.length; n++) {
      if(coll[n] == this) continue;
      coll[n].classList.remove("active");
   }
    
    this.classList.toggle("active"); 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible.active + .content {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When running your code snippet b is not defined in your loop. believe it should be n?

Comment: Thank you very much, I choose to apply this because it has the least changes to html and css, Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your code was quite confusing for me to decipher, so I just re-wrote it in what I would consider a clear way. This was achieved by creating two functions to open or close the submenu for a particular element.

```js
var buttoncolumn = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');

function closesubmenu(el) {
  el.setAttribute('id', '');
  el.classList.remove('active');
  el.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
}

function opensubmenu(el) {
  el.setAttribute('id', 'submenuopened');
  el.classList.add('active');
  el.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
}

for (let button of buttoncolumn) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.getAttribute('id') == 'submenuopened') {
      closesubmenu(this);
    } else {
      for (let other of buttoncolumn) {
        closesubmenu(other);
      }
      opensubmenu(this);
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```